# Constructing lambdas in constructors

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, object-construction

I had some nasty bugs when constructing lambdas in constructors when working with callback-based event system.
Here's simple scenario:

```
class Object {
public:
    int variable = 10;
    std::function<void()> callback;

    Object() {
        callback = [this]() {
            variable += 10;
        };
    }
};

class ObjectReceiver {
public:
    Object object;

    explicit ObjectReceiver(Object &&hi) : object(std::move(hi)) {}
};

int main() {
    ObjectReceiver receiver{Object()};
    receiver.object.callback();
    std::cout << receiver.object.variable << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, "10" will be printed, because the object was moved, and pointer that lambda is holding, invalidated.

This means that in code outside of `Object`, i should always care, whether it constructs lambda in it's constructor.

How to deal with such problems? Should i make general convention for myself to not construct lambdas from constructors?

Comment: The lambda in the constructor is not an issue. Capturing `this` pointing to a destroyed temporary Object is the issue.

Comment: @273K I understand that lambda itself is not issue. But what would you do in such cases, if you have event system with callbacks? How to avoid such invalidation. Would you avoid passing objects around like i did here, or would you avoid creating lambdas in constructors?

Comment: I would add a moving constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the call `receiver.object.callback();` is operating with an argument `this` that points to the temporary instance of `Object` created by the constructor `Object()` in `ObjectReceiver receiver{Object()};`.  Even if you pass everything by value and avoid move semantics altogether you will still have the same problem.  The underlying issue is that `this` is passed by value and not updated when move semantics are applied to copying the temporary instance of `Object` to the instance stored in `receiver.object`.

To make it work, you need to make the lambda relative to the instance of `Object` to which it applies with something like:

```
class Object {
public:
    int variable = 10;
    std::function<void(Object& o)> raw_callback;
    void callback() { raw_callback (*this); }

    Object() {
        raw_callback = [](Object& o) {
            o.variable += 10;
        };
    }
};
```